# Javascript - Putting element in a var but can't change style

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is called when an element is clicked.

```
function showHide(elem){    
        var clickedText = elem.getElementsByTagName("p");
        clickedText.style.color = "green";

    }
```

When I run this code I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined`. However, if I do `console.log(clickedText)` it logs the appropriate

tag. Can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working, have I missed something totally obvious?

Comment: do you want to change the background color of the tags ?

Comment: @SrinivasB dude, the game's over

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) method returns a collection of elements (in a `NodeList`, which is like an array).

You will need to specify an index. For example:

```
clickedText[0].style.color = "green";
```

Currently, you're trying to access the `style` property of the `NodeList` itself, rather than an element contained within it.

Comment: Or better give it an id and use `getElementsById()`

Comment: GODDAMN! I knew it was something simple like this, I'm only just starting learning to code and trying to get my head around stuff like this. Thanks mate!

Comment: @Mr.Alien - I don't think it needs an `id` because the code shown is looking for paragraphs within another, known element.

Comment: @nnnnnn oh yes I saw, it's nested

Answer (score 5):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a list of elements, so you need to loop through the results:

```
var clickedTexts = elem.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i = 0; i < clickedTexts.length; i++) { 
    clickedTexts[i].style.color = "green";
}
```